# javascript, limit number of characters in text field

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form which allows only for numbers to be entered in the text box, or an alert appears:

```
<form name="formName" action="" method="post" OnSubmit="return chkSubmit();"> 
    Input Number 
    <input type="text" name="txtNumber" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

with the following javascript:

```
<script>
function chkSubmit()
{
     if(isNaN(document.formName.txtNumber.value))
     {
        alert('Please input numbers only.');
        return false;
     }
}</script>
```

How do I allow for only 4 characters to be entered?  No alert, just prevent the user from typing more than 4 characters.

Comment: Restricting input like that is annoying for users. You only care that the field is valid when the form is submitted, whatever it contains before then is of no interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input` elements support a [`maxlength` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-maxlength), e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="txtNumber" value="" maxlength="4">
```

...which is then enforced by the user agent (browser). You can also enforce it in your `chkSubmit` if you want a belt-and-braces approach, by checking the length of the `value` property, but it's been around forever and I doubt you'll find a user agent that doesn't handle it.

RobG's point (in a comment on the question) is well-taken, as well: Restricting users prior to form submission tends to be irritating for them. It may or may not be appropriate for your use-case, but at least consider not limiting them (but perhaps giving some visual feedback using the `keypress` event), and only validating length on submit, the way Stack Overflow does on comments.

Comment: as in 
<input type="text" name="whatever" maxlength="20">

Answer (score 1):

Use **maxlength**

```
<form name="formName" action="" method="post" OnSubmit="return chkSubmit();"> 
    <input type="text" name="txtNumber" maxlength="4" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```